# python move file based on dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to move specific files(only ending with *.txt) from folders under /home/wiet/import/ directory(recursive) search. But I want to do it based on the dictionary-so for example in folder /home/wiet/import/OS only files with ending *windows.txt, or  *rhel.txt should be moved-about other files I want information in console about not matching files(and preferably add them to some list). For now I've got this one below, but I cannot match it with dictionary and I've got problem with copying correct files to another directory

```
import sys
import os
import shutil
import glob
import fnmatch
tech = {"OS": ["rhel.txt", "windows.txt"]
        "DB" : ["mysql.txt","oracle.txt","postgres.txt","postgresql.txt"],
        "WEB" : ["iis.txt" , "apache.txt", "tomcat.txt" ] ,
        }

fileslist = []
txtcorrect = []
destin = "/home/wiet/import"
print "part1 \n \n \n"


path = os.path.join(destin)
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(destin):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.txt'):
        print "found: " + name
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):
                txtcorrect.replace(os.path.join(root, filename))
                print txtcorrect
                shutil.copy2( txtcorrect , '/home/wiet/out')
```

Comment: A `walk()` inside a `walk()` seems a bit strange to me, doesn't the outer walk visit all directories already?

Comment: ok good point-but still I'm looking how to match path with dictionary key and its values

Comment: What is the error message/observed result? The last line with `copy2()` looks suspicious, `txtcorrect` is still a list, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want.

Hope this helps:

```
.... 
....   
for key in tech:
    if name in tech[key]:
        '''do something'''
....
....
```

Comment: How does it relate to the question? Could you use the same variable names, or add some more context around?